# Full lunar mineralization/ore map

Tags: the-moon, mining, natural-resources, mapping

This is really quick I'm searching for a full complete ore map of the moon, I found this:

[image]

But, as you can see, is impossible read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the labelled version you found of the USGS map [large enough to read the text](https://stargazerslounge.com/uploads/monthly_2020_04/Unified_Geologic_Map_of_The_Moon_200dpi.jpg.3f73a13d6cb5083574ad869a40dca057.jpg)

For completion's sake, here's a mirror, **limited by the 2MB upload size of SE**, so it's only barely readable. The link above has a much higher resolution

[image: USGS map]

Here's also the key only in somewhat higher resolution, which is likely reusable between all versions of the map.

[image: key only]

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Universe Today website](https://www.universetoday.com/145887/want-to-mine-the-moon-heres-a-detailed-map-of-all-its-minerals/), the [US Geological Service](https://www.usgs.gov/news/usgs-releases-first-ever-comprehensive-geologic-map-moon) (USGS) has produced a geological map of the Moon, that is [available online](https://www.usgs.gov/media/videos/unified-geologic-map-moon).

[image]

This is also an animation of the globe of the Moon.

The map in the picture included in your question can be downloaded from the USGS website and it is possible to zoom in on the map and legend to see the detail.

Comment: yhea, but what mineral is what colour? i check the web, and i download the ~200MB zip with the .jpg, but i dont understeand what mineral reprecent what colour.